# Removing title content from page html

Tags: php, regex

Here I am creating preview for url. Which shows

1. Url title
2. Url description (title should not come in this)

Here is my try.

```
<?php
function plaintext($html)
    {
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#', ' ', $html);

        // remove title 
            //$plaintext = preg_match('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $html);

        // remove comments and any content found in the the comment area (strip_tags only removes the actual tags).
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#<!--.*?-->#s', '', $plaintext);

        // put a space between list items (strip_tags just removes the tags).
            $plaintext = preg_replace('#</li>#', ' </li>', $plaintext);     

            // remove all script and style tags
        $plaintext = preg_replace('#<(script|style)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</(script|style)>#is', "", $plaintext);

        // remove br tags (missed by strip_tags)
            $plaintext = preg_replace("#<br[^>]*?>#", " ", $plaintext);

            // remove all remaining html
            $plaintext = strip_tags($plaintext);

        return $plaintext;
    }
        function get_title($html) 
    {
        return preg_match('!<title>(.*?)</title>!i', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
    }
        function trim_display($size,$string)
    {
        $trim_string = substr($string, 0, $size);

        $trim_string = $trim_string . "...";
        return $trim_string;
    }

$url = "http://www.nextbigwhat.com/indian-startups/";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
//$url = trim_url(5,$url);      
    $title = get_title($data);
        echo "title is ; $title";   
    $content = plaintext($data); 
    $Preview = trim_display(100,$content);
echo '<br/>';
echo "preview is: $Preview";

?>
```

URL title appear correctly. But when I have excluded the title content from description, even it appear.

i have uses `$plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#', ' ', $html);` to exclude the title from plain text.

Regex is correct as per me event it does not exclude title content.

What is the problem here?

output we get here is:

```
title is ; Indian Startups Archives - NextBigWhat.com
preview is: Indian Startups Archives : NextBigWhat.com [whatever rest text]...
```

Actually the text which appears in title part should not again come in preview. That's why i want to exclude it and display rest text in preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**how to solve the mistery**

If you look closer to the title and the preview, they're different. Let's see the output from the curl.

```
echo plaintext($data);
```

Well, it seems it has two titles:

```
<title>
Indian Startups Archives : NextBigWhat.com</title>
```

and

```
<title>Indian Startups Archives - NextBigWhat.com</title>
```

Then the `get_title` function is retrieving the second title and `plaintext` leaves alone the first one. What's the difference between them? the line break! therefore your regex isn't matching titles with newline characters, which is why the /s option modifier in regular expressions exists!

**tl;dr**

Your regex is wrong, add 's'  to it.

```
$plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#s', ' ', $html);`
```

instead of

```
$plaintext = preg_replace('#([<]title)(.*)([<]/title[>])#', ' ', $html);`
```

Comment: thanks, what you mean by two title? code  has only one title i think

Comment: 's' what decision maker!

Comment: I forgot it, sorry buddy!